# Windows 10 - Critical Process Died BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

Whenever I attempt to boot windows 10 (64 bit), I get the error in title. I am able to access the recovery command prompt.

`chkdsk C: /f /r` says that there are no problems.

`sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=c:\windows`  says "Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested action."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try running SFC "normally" :

Admin command prompt,  SFC /SCANNOW  .

It that fails and it appears your disk is OK (CHKDSK ran), then try first updating ALL Drivers.

If all the above fails, back up your data and reinstall Windows. Given the nature of the error, this may be the fastest way.

Comment: It fails with the same error just using /scannow.  with the flags in the post, it fails instantly, but without them, it gets to 100% and then fails. How do I update my drivers from the recovery command prompt?

Comment: Try starting in Safe Mode and if that does not work, then just back up and start over.

Comment: did you tried boot last known configuration?

Comment: Try using DISM for repair: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image However, if that fails, reinstalling Windows from USB, as @John suggests, may be faster than trying many other fixes.